# how to create a firefox extension that add Context Menu Item that call localhost URL

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to create a click-to-dial firefox extension like [image: this] in which an item is shown in the context menu when selecting a phone number( lets say it's 123456). When clicking on this item a localhost URL "http://localhost:49324/Home/Index?tel=123456" should be called (This URL is always listening).

So what i don't know is :

1. how to call a localhost URL in my js script
2. how to pass the phone number to my js and then to my localhost URL
3. How to add contexte menu item

i've tried to follow [This tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Context_Menu_Item) that explains how to add a context menu but it didn't work (i guess that it's because my manifest.json script)

My manifest.json script is :
    {

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "OBS_Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["OBS_Extension.js"]
  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/dial.png",
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]

}
```

My OBS_Extension.js script is :

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Click-To-Dial",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    console.log(selectionText);
  }
});
```